# C++ Condense Two for-loops to Improve Efficiency

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of structs that I need to retrive data from. The array holds names and scores.

For one function I have to output the highest score and the name associated. If there are multiple cases I must output all names.

I CANNOT USE VECTORS or LISTS. (else I would) I just want to perform both actions in the same step.

This is how I'm handling it:

```
void highScorer (  player array[], int size )
{ // highScorer

    int highScore = 0; //variable to hold the total score

    // first loop determines highest score
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {

        if ( array[i].pointsScored > highScore ) {
            highScore = array[i].pointsScored;            
        }
    }
    cout << "\nThe highest scoring player(s) were:\n";
    // second loop finds players with scores matching highScore and prints their name(s)
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        // when a match is found, the players name is printed out
        if ( array[i].pointsScored == highScore ) {
            cout << array[i].playerName;
            cout << ", scored ";
            // conditional will output correct grammar
            if ( array[i].pointsScored > 1 ) {
                cout << array[i].pointsScored << " points!\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << array[i].pointsScored << " point!\n";
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n"; // add new line for readability
    return;

} // highScorer
```

I would like to condense this to one for loop. Unless someone has a suggestion for an even more efficient method. I would think sorting the data would be unnecessary. Plus if it's sorted, how could determine if there were more than one "highScore" case in one step.

Comment: Making two passes is typical in this situation, it's still linear.  If you really want you could keep a list of indexes, and then empty it when a new highscore is found.

Comment: Minor nitpicks: `return;` is unnecessary at the end of a `void` function and some of your comments are excessive (I'm looking at you, `// add new line for readability`).

Comment: hahaha! Man I totally agree with you @Brendan Long but it's homework and they want excessive commenting. Still, you're right about that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to record the names of the players as you're searching for the high score.  If it's equal to the current high score, then append an additional name to your "collection of names string", and if it's higher, blank out the names, and record the new high score and new name as well.  I'd implement the printout of names as an `ostringstream` to ensure you don't run over a buffer.  Then when you're done, print out your set of names.

Comment: A TA made this suggestion but said to use an array. I was like "How do you append arrays?" but didn't say anything. Good idea just keeping a string though. I'll see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @frankV Since you know the size of the list (`int size` in your parameters), you could create an array with `new int[size]`, as long as you `delete[]` it later. It's not as good as using a `vector` but it's probably what they expect.

Comment: I tried that. The compiler through up a red flag. The only method I found for getting the elemental size of an array was `int sizeOfArray = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);` you can't reuse this to declare another array for some reason.

Comment: You can't use a non-`const` variable as an array length specifier.  Array sizes are declared at compile-time, and thus the compiler needs to know the size.  If it's a variable, that can change prior to declaration.  You CAN use a variable to declare an array on the heap though with the `new[]` operator, but that's beyond the scope of what you're doing right now.  Hint: the dominant reason you ever need to calculate the size of a non-heap array is serialization.  If you "need" to in another way, you're probably doing it wrong.  It should already be somewhere else you can read, not calculate.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to your `highScore` variable you make a second variable, for example a `std::list` (or a manual linked list or even a small array, depending on what you're allowed to use). In this list you keep track of the indices of the people that actually have the current highscore. If a new highscore is found you clear that list and add the person with the new highscore. If someone is found that has the highscore you simply add him to the list.

Then after looping you only need to print the players with the indices in this list, rather than find out again who has the highscore.

Comment: I bet that if `std::vector` is off-limits, then so will `std::list` be.

Comment: @larsmans: yes, I changed my answer right before your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the set of indexes of the highest score so far as you go through the first (only) pass.  Then when you're done, you'll already have the set of indexes that correspond to that highest score. In pseudocode for a language that I just made up:

```
int highestSoFar = 0;
list indexesOfHighScore = new list();

for (int i = 0; i < scores.count; i++) {
    if (scores[i] > highestSoFar) {
        highestSoFar = scores[i];
        indexesOfHighScore.empty();
    }
    if (scores[i] == highestSoFar) {
        indexesOfHighScore.add(i);
    }
}

// Now I know the highest score, and all the indexes of entries that correspond to it.
```

If you don't have a dynamic list available, the list could be a static array of the same size as the scores array to ensure that it's always big enough.

Comment: This is basically what I described.

Comment: @frankV: "List" is an abstract concept here. You can keep a "list" using many different kinds of data structures. For example, you can create a new array for this (requires using the same size as the original list to make sure everything fits in the worst case).

Comment: @frankV: (I also used the term "set" interchangeably with "list" here. Since indexes are unique and the order of high scoring indexes is probably (?) not important, "set" is the better concept. Same implementation options apply.)

Answer (score 1):

Right now your first loop is keeping track of the high score. If it also kept track of all the matching names, you could output the names when the loop was finished. You'd still need a second loop to go through those names, that can't be avoided.

Comment: It takes less additional memory to store the indices, rather than the names themselves. And this is also the same as my answer :)

Comment: @nightcracker: depends on whether a "name" is an `std::string` or a `char const*`.

Comment: @nightcracker, I think there were about 4 new answers created while I was writing mine - late to the party I guess. And you're right about the indices.

Comment: @larsmans: always cheatin' with them pointers :) Though you could probably get away with using `uint16_t`'s to store the indices. Hah!

Comment: @nightcracker, one more thing: I tend to be a little vague when the question smells like homework.

Answer (score 1):

At a small cost in storage, you can compute the high score and the respective players in the same pass:

```
player ** highScorer (  player array[], int size )
{
    player ** result = new player*[size + 1]; // The +1 handles the case where everyone ties

    int highScore = 0;
    int foundAt = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        if ( array[i].pointsScored > highScore )
        {
            highScore = array[i].pointsScored;
            foundAt = 0;
        }

        if ( array[i].pointsScored == highScore )
        {
            result[foundAt] = &(array[i]);
            foundAt++;
        }
    }

    result[foundAt] = null; // Stopping condition, hence the +1 earlier

    return result; // Remember to delete[] the resulting array
}
```

However.

That won't give you an output. You will still need a second loop if you want to output your results.

```
void outputScores ( player ** result )
{
    cout << "\nThe highest scoring player(s) were:\n";

    for ( int i = 0; result[i] != null; i++ )
    {
        cout << result[i]->playerName;
        cout << ", scored ";
        if ( result[i]->pointsScored == 1 )
            cout << "1 point!\n";
        else
            cout << result[i]->pointsScored << " points!\n";
    }

    cout << "\n";

    delete [] result;
}
```

To answer your original question, I don't think there is any way whatsoever of finding *and* outputting all the players having the high score, in a single loop. Even pre-sorting the score array would be worse than what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than keeping the complete set of matching indices, I would just keep the first and last.  That lets you skip searching the entire list, and avoids the second pass completely in the case where there's a unique highest score.

```
void highScorer( player* array, int size )
{
    int highScore = 0;
    int firstHighI = -1, lastHighI = -1;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {  
        if ( array[i].pointsScored > highScore ) {
            highScore = array[i].pointsScored;
            firstHighI = i;
        }
        if ( array[i].pointsScored == highScore ) {
            lastHighI = i;
        }
    }

    if (firstHighI >= 0) {
        std::cout << "\nThe highest scoring player(s) were:\n";
        for ( int i = firstHighI; i < lastHighI; i++ ) {
            if ( array[i].pointsScored == highScore ) {
                std::cout << array[i].playerName << ", ";
            }
        }

        std::cout << array[lastHighI].playerName << " with a score of " << highScore;
        if ( highScore != 1 ) {
            std::cout << " points!\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << " point!\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```